# How to pass multiple reminders in react native firebase push notification?

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm working on a scheduled local push notification in react native using firebase. I've successfully generated a notification on a specific time like this:

```
  firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(this.buildNotification(), {
    fireDate: notificationTime.valueOf(), //a specific date is set using a datetimepicker
    repeatInterval: "minute",
    exact: true
  });
```

My question is how can I set multiple reminders in `scheduleNotification()`? Is is possible in react-native-firebase?

Answer (score 2):

Yes is possible in react-native-firebase

In your buildNotification

```
  buildNotification = (notificationId) => {
    const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
       .setNotificationId(notificationId)  --> set here different  id    
   return notification;
};
```

repeatInterval: 'day',

How frequently the notification should be repeated. One of minute, 
   hour, day or week.

If not present, the notification will be displayed once.